# Passing an element id from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

I have some data from my mysql database. I am showing that data in table using foreach loop like below

```
<table> 
foreach($students as $row):?>
        <tr><td><i id="expand<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>" class="myclass fa fa-plus-square"></i></td>
        <td><?php echo $i; $i++;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['roll'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><img src="<?php echo $this->crud_model->get_image_url('student',$row['student_id']);?>" class="img-circle" width="50" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>

            <td><?php echo $row['address'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['phone'];?></td></tr></table>
```

I have also a click event function in Javascript like below

```
$('#expand').click(function(){
    $('#dev').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

This is I want to hide and show on clicked event. Please note that this row contains data of student whose student id is $row['student_id']

```
 <tr id="dev<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>" class="hidden">
            <td colspan="7">
            <table>
            <tr><td>Phone Number is <?php echo $row['phone'];?></td></tr>
            </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
```

I want to pass element id from php to javascipt so that when clicked on id **expand** it will execute some function like showing or hiding

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far to accomplish this task? What went wrong with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an `id` called `"expand"`, you have this:

```
id="expand<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>"
```

Assuming `$row['student_id']` isn't empty (and it shouldn't be, at least for more than one record, since `id`s need to be unique), then the `id` won't be `"expand"`.  It *will*, however, *begin with* `"expand"`.  So you can [select on that](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[id^="expand"]').click(function(){
    // handle the click event here
});
```

This will attach the same `click` handler to each matched item, which is any element on the page where the `id` begins with `"expand"`.  Note that the handler is going to do the same thing for each one, so your current logic targets one single element (with an `id` of `"dev"`) to toggle its visibility.  So, currently, every click will show/hide the same element.  You might not want *exactly* that functionality, but that's not entirely included in the question.  (There's no `#dev` element in your markup, so it's not entirely clear how you want it to behave.)

**Edit**

There are a number of ways to target the element you want to show/hide.  Without having to change the markup, you can probably just [get the numeric portion of the `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and use that to build the target `id`.  Potentially something like this:

```
$('[id^="expand"]').click(function(){
    var idNumber = $(this).attr('id').replace(/expand/g, '');
    $('#dev'+id).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Thanks David, Your answer works but it shows/hide only first hidden row. not other. Can u tell how to show/hide the element relative to button clicked

Comment: @BWCreativePanipat: Where is that element in relation to that button?  There are lots of jQuery selectors/functions for traversing the DOM to target a specific element.  Your current selector is based on `id`, so it can only ever target one element because `id`s need to be unique.

Comment: when user click on expand1 id then dev1 id will be show and when click on expand2 id, dev2 id will be shown like this.

Comment: @BWCreativePanipat: I've updated the answer.  If the `id` elements will always follow that same pattern of a known text portion followed by the same numeric portion then some quick string manipulation can do the job without having to change the markup.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all participants

But special thanks to @david & @deacs

I have got it working as below

```
$('[id^="expand"]').click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
$('#dev'+id).toggleClass('hidden');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute to the element.

```
<i id="expand<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>" data-id="<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>" class="myclass fa fa-plus-square"></i>
```

Call function on class not on id as there are multiple elements.

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('#dev-'+id).toggleClass('hidden'); // apply proper logic here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `.myclass` in the selector and then remove the string `expand` from the `id` which you retrieve from `attr()`:

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('expand','');
    $('#dev'+id).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```